# How do I disable SELinux for a subprocess launched from Apache?

Tags: linux, security, selinux

[My Apache module](http://www.modrails.com) launches a helper subprocess which does, for example, but not limited by, the following things:

- It sets up a socket so that it can communicate with Apache.
- Reads and writes files in a temporary location that is deleted when Apache exits. These files are used e.g. for storing large amounts of data received over the network, in case that data does not comfortably fit in RAM.
- It spawns user-specified executables. Similar to CGI. Each of these spawned processes are run as their own dedicated user.

The helper subprocess is launched as root so that it can manage file ownerships and permissions and can spawn more processes as specific users.

Some users of my module run on systems with SELinux installed, e.g. RedHat-based distros. SELinux usually interferes with my module. Until now I've been telling people to disable SELinux system-wide because I can't figure out how to write a proper policy for my software. Documentation is very scattered, complex and usually only targets system administrators, not software developers.

As a step into the right direction, I want to implement minimal support for SELinux. I'm looking for a way to launch my helper subprocess without any SELinux constraints without disabling SELinux system-wide. Is there a way to do that, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... you *could* write a rule that transitions your domain to `unconfined_t`, but then you'd piss off quite a few sysadmins. Best to write yourself a new domain that inherits from `httpd_t` and also adds the appropriate contexts for access.

Comment: I know that but right now I *already* tell people to disable SELinux entirely, and they're still willing to use my software. I can't aim for perfection the first time, I want an intermediate solution that doesn't take too long to learn and to implement.

Comment: And how does loading that rule work? Am I supposed to write a policy file, fork() a process, then call some SELinux API to load said policy file, then exec() my helper program?

Comment: Very little of SELinux is actually programming; it's mostly policy. Your policy file contains the new domain, a new file context for your executable, a transition rule from `httpd_t` to your new domain, and a file context for any executables it must run that don't already have one. You load the compiled SELinux module, relabel the executables as required, and then it just all runs.

Comment: So exec() will look at the executable file's SELinux context and automatically assign that SELinux context to the executed process and load the right policy file?

Comment: There's only one system policy, so there's no need to load anything else once the module has been loaded by the administrator via `semanage`. SELinux will use the current domain and the executable file's context as a lookup in the policy in order to find the domain that it should transition the new process into. So, if `httpd` running in `httpd_t` runs an executable with the `myapp_bin_t` context, and the policy specifies a transition on those to `myapp_t`, then the new process will run in the `myapp_t` domain.

Comment: What happens then if the executable that's spawned from Apache doesn't have a policy? Will it still be confined according to Apache's policies or will it run unconfined with no policies?

Comment: If there's no transition rule from one domain to another then SELinux will deny the action, except in the case where the source domain is `unconfined_t`.